# Use checkboxGroupInput to filter data for use in output in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create an app where I can select names from a list to send a text message reminder to. I'm using checkboxGroupInput to select the names from a dataframe containing names and phone numbers. I want to then subset the dataframe based on that selection and loop through the selected rows and send a text to each phone number in that frame. Lastly, I want to create a list of names that were sent the text message and include in the alert upon submitting the form.

I've removed the text message function from the code below just to keep it simple. Any help with where I've gone wrong would be great!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyforms)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyTime)
library(shinyalert)

#get data
all_data=data.frame(name=c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"),
                phone_number=c(11111111,22222222,33333333,44444444))


shinyApp(
    
    #define app
    ui <- fluidPage(
        
        titlePanel("Shiny App"),
        checkboxGroupInput('names', 'Names',
                           choices=all_data$name),
        useShinyalert(),
        actionButton("submit", "Submit")
        
    ),
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
        
        data <- reactive({
            df <- all_data[all_data$name %in% input$names,]
            return(df)
        })
        
        #completed=paste(data$Name, collapse = ', ')  ### NOT WORKING
        
        # When the Submit button is clicked, send the text messages
        observeEvent(input$submit, {
            
            for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
                
                ### FUNCTION TO SEND TEXT ###
                
            }
            
            shinyalert("Reminder Sent!", completed, type = "success")
        })
        
    })


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: When you refer to a `reactive` expression you should use `data()` with parentheses instead of just `data`

Comment: Thanks @Ben, that seemed to work for most of the problems, but I am still having problems getting the below part to work. Could you help with that part? `#completed=paste(data$Name, collapse = ', ')  ### NOT WORKING`

Comment: Same thing - try `completed = paste(data()$Name, collapse = ', ')` ... just add parentheses (also may be lower case 'n' in name?)